# Hive - Remove leading and trailing new line characters?

Tags: sql, hive, special-characters, hiveql, trim

`trim()` function in hive does't remove leading and trailing new line characters. is there any alternative solution to do it except UDF?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp_replace function.

```
select regexp_replace(col_name,'^\\n*|\\n*$','')
```

it will remove leading and trailing newlines. If there are windows style newlines \r\n, use this:

```
regexp_replace(col_name,'^(\\r\\n)*|(\\r\\n)*$','')
```